# Is there a spanish Sentiment Analysis Dataset

Tags: r

I've been looking for a library similar to sentimentR. I have read multiple papers performing SA in spanish, but none of them tell the source they are using.

Please confirm if there is a datast available.

Comment: @OTStats ... this and previous question should be closed. It is off-topic to recommend software on Stackoverflow including libraries, modules, tutorials, and off-site resources. OP needs to do their own research. Google/Bing are a click away!

Comment: Check TASS 2020 dataset http://tass.sepln.org/2020/